SWD interface DEMUX
I need to flash 8 ARM Cortex M7 MCUs one at a time using a single J-link through SWD. From what I understand, the key pins to focus on are SWDIO, SWDCLK, and nReset, since ground and VCC are shared. Does anyone have suggestions for a low-cost Mux/Demux that could handle this? I’m aware that using three 8-channel analog multiplexers/demultiplexers (like the 74HC4051) would work, but I’m hoping there’s a solution that requires fewer ICs.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could you get more specific about MCU part number ? Some MCUs SW-DP do support SWD-Multidrop and basically implement what you are looking for for free. Alternatively, if MCU has support for JTAG programming, you may chain all JTAG-DPs.
